# Angular 7, subtract calendar days from date input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

In this Angular 7 app, a user needs to select a date from a calendar input, then generate what the day is 40 days earlier.  I have not been able to figure this out in Typescript.  There are a lot of JavaScript solutions out there, but I do not know how to convert those into an Angular-friendly typescript version.  Right now I have two functions both trying to do this (Generate 1 & Generate 2), neither work.

**Generate 1** is suppose to use the 'add-subtract-date' I imported (npm), but I'm getting the Typescript error...  "error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'."

**Generate 2** has no errors, just does nothing.
I do not think my HTML is correct either.  I'm open to any new ideas, just please include the HTML as well.

component.ts...

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalculatorService } from '../calculator.service';
import { add, subtract } from 'add-subtract-date';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  lastWorkingDay: any;
  isWeekday: string;

  public fortyDaysDate: any;



    private _retireSet: Date;
   get retireSet(): Date {
    return this._retireSet;
   }
   set retireSet(value: Date) {
    this._retireSet = value;

  }


  constructor(private calculatorService: CalculatorService) { 
  } 

  ngOnInit() {

  }


//Generate 1, this worked when using "const d: Date = new Date()"
public daysForty(): any {
  const d: Date = this.retireSet;
  const fortyDaysBack = subtract(d, 40, "days");
  this.fortyDaysDate = fortyDaysBack; 
}


// Generate 2, this does not work
  protected generateLastWorkingDay(): Date {
    const lastWorkingDay = new Date(Date.now()); 
    while(!this.isWorkingDay(lastWorkingDay)) {
      lastWorkingDay.setDate(lastWorkingDay.getDate()-40);
    }    
    return lastWorkingDay;
  }    
  private isWorkingDay(date: Date) {
    const day = date.getDay();
    const isWeekday = (day > 0 && day < 6);
    return isWeekday; 
  }





}
```

component.html...

```
  <form>
        <div class="container">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=""retireSet"">Set Date</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" id=""retireSet"" 
      name="RetireCalculatorSetDate" value="retireSet" ngModel 
      #RetireCalculatorSetDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="retireSet" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="staffID">Staff ID</label>
            <input type="text" id="staffID" name="RetireCalculatorStaffID"
                   [(ngModel)]="RetireCalculatorStaffID" 
                class="form-control" /> 
</div>


        <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                        (click)="daysForty()">Generate 1</button>       
                <input type="text" name="RetireCalculatorDay45" value="fortyDaysDate" ngModel #RetireCalculatorDay45="ngModel" 
                [(ngModel)]="fortyDaysDate" class="form-control" />        
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="generateLastWorkingDay()"> Generate 2 </button>    
            <input type="date" class="text-field w-input" name="LastWorkingDay" 
                   value="LastWorkingDay" [(ngModel)]="LastWorkingDay" />
        </div>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  (click)="sendForm($event)">Submit</button>

        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: TypeScript is JavaScript.  Why can't you use the JS versions?

Comment: When I try to enter JS in Visual Studio Code, I get errors.  Then I'm not sure how to access the JS results in the HTML.  I'm still a Jr. Dev (if you haven't noticed).  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What kind of errors? Can you edit your question with the code that is problematic

Comment: I would also recommend using momentjs [https://momentjs.com/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the import incorrectly. Remember that you're importing the function not an object.

```
import { add, subtract } from 'add-subtract-date';
...

//Generate 1
public daysForty(): Date {
  const d: Date = new Date();
  const fortyDaysBack = subtract(d, 40, "days"); // Check this. does subtract() manipulate "d" or create a new date?
  return fortyDaysBack;
}
```

Your second functions is a bit confusing. The function name indicates it will generate the LastWorkingDay. However, the logic is confusing with the while loop.

Comment: Thank you that did get rid of the compiling error.  But I do not know how to show the results in my HTML.  I have "fortyDaysBack" in the input [(ngModel)], and function called on button click.  I would like results in the input field.  Shouldn't this function use today's current date?

Comment: I would print the date as a string. Here is a function I found on the internet that could help. [disclaimer] I have not tested this.

function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));  // show current date-time in console

Comment: If you're going to be manipulating dates a lot I strongly suggest library specifically meant for this. The only one I've used is momentJs

Comment: The value of "d" and "fortyDaysBack" are calculating correctly, but after the return statement in the function, they have no value.  Again, I can't get the values to show up in the HTML.

Comment: In your code you are calling daysForty() with a (click) event, and then returning the variable to the event handler. You also use addSubtractDate as a defined const within the daysForty() method, that const is out of scope for your html and will not work in the ngModel. Make addSubtractDate a public variable in the class scope and assign its value rather than return it from the daysForty() method.

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help jriver27 and @Marshal.  I updated my code with corrections, as it all works now!  You guys rock.

Comment: I thought if I could get the daysForty() function working with the current date, that I could easily swap that out with the value from the date selected in the "RetireCalculatorSetDate" input. Sadly this is not working. I've updated my code with the getter setter, trying to use the variable "this.retireSet" instead of current date. Can you and @Marshal please take a look and let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong?  The browser error says... TypeError: d.getDate is not a function

Comment: As this question is already marked with an accepted answer, please raise a new question with your new issue and I will review once available.

Comment: @jriver27, do you think it's possible for the "daysForty()" function to change 3 different values with one click?  You did a great job fixing my first function, so wanted to ask.  I think it's a syntax error in my nested function.  I posted this in a different stack here (no one has any suggestions yet)...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050431/angular-7-nested-function-using-same-variable?noredirect=1#comment93000667_53050431